# Connecting 2 floodlights to 1 sensor

Tags: wiring

I have an existing pair of floodlights with a sensor and would like to add an additional pair of floodlights to be tied into that same sensor.  Any suggestions on wiring this up?  Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: What make and model are the existing and new floodlights?

Comment: Are the floods incandescent, LED or fluorescent? A single switch might not handle the current inrush of four incandesecnt lamps, but the other types should be OK. Just wire the lampholders in parallel, white-to-white, black-to-black, ground-to-ground.

Comment: Seems like your question could use a lot more detail. Most commonly available today at a typical hardware/home-improvement store would be a single fixture with two LED heads and an integrated motion sensor. It would be non-trivial to connect those, unless you find a make/model that is specifically designed to be chained together. If it's some other type, it _might_ be more feasible, but there's really no way to know, given how little information there is in the question.

Comment: Did you ever get this working? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer that helped you the most, or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer

Answer (score 1):

I have put up to 20 lamps on a single sensor, your sensor needs to be able to handle the total current of all the lamps combined. You use the same neutral and ground to the fixture then tap the switched hot, most of the time this is red but usually says load, take those 3 wires to the new fixture and connect them up and now you have your additional light. If exterior to the home in conduit , if you can go back inside and run to the next box conduit may not be needed.
Note if you add more wattage than the controller can handle it will let the magic smoke out and quit working.